# Character sequence string matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

I'm googling my brains out trying to find the name of this type of algorithm. It is a string searching algorithm where the order of the characters in the pattern must be preserved when matching the text, but not all characters in the pattern must be present in the haystack.

For example: `cat` would match `cart` because all the characters in `cat` appear in order in `cart`. And `cat` would also match `click` because `click` contains `c`.

You can see this algorithm in action in the Chrome debug tools if you search for a file:

[Algorithm in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96I6M.png)

What is the name of this algorithm?

Comment: So basically any two strings match as soon as they contain a common character?

Comment: Possibly called subsequence matching, or more generally [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)?

Comment: So `cat` matches `crater` but how about `catastrophe`..?

Comment: Are you sure that cat matches click? I think cat should match crate but not creta or click, and creta...t... or click...a...t... would be a match again. Does the algorithm need a name? It's really easy to detect in O(n), where n is the length of the string to check.

Comment: Subsequence matching looks promising. 

I recall reading about this kind of search algorithm in relation to autocomplete/intellisense. I thought it had a name.

From the screenshot you can see that even if a single character matches, Chrome would show the result. It appears to have some kind of scoring mechanism too. I'm not having any luck grepping Chrome's source code for it.